# Unable to depend on Q via requirejs under Karma

Tags: javascript, debugging, requirejs, karma-runner, q

In my project [ChuckJS](https://github.com/aknuds1/chuckjs/tree/977df75cd1a0285e365039c9e3015067219d5e0c) (be aware that it's GPL licensed) I'm running into this issue when trying to depend on [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) via [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/), when running the project's Karma tests. What happens is that RequireJS throws this exception: *Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module*. I've found that the exception is thrown on line 1219 of require.js:

```
if (args[0] === null) {
    return onError(makeError('mismatch', 'Mismatched anonymous define() module: ' + args[args.length - 1]));
}
```

The reason that args[0] is null is that the module in question (Q) is anonymous and hence hasn't supplied a name. The callstack at the time of the exception is:

- require.js line 1219
- require.js line 1404

I haven't been able to reproduce the issue separately; not sure exactly why, but in that case the Q module definition wasn't fetched from line 1404, so it seems that there are several ways that dependencies can be applied within RequireJS.

So, how can I resolve this issue, i.e. load Q via RequireJS in ChuckJS without complaints?

Comment: Did you follow the checklist at the end of the documentation on the [error](http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch) you get?

Comment: @Louis Argh, I'm such a dolt. I'd instructed Karma (via karma.conf.js) to effectively load q.js statically (although that wasn't my intention). Thanks and merry Christmas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in how Q was included via Karma, i.e. it was effectively included statically in karma.conf.js:

```
files: [
    'test-main.coffee',
    [...]
    '../node_modules/q/q.js'
],
```

To let RequireJS load Q dynamically, the inclusion in karma.conf.js has to be as follows (note the `included: false` bit):

```
files: [
    'test-main.coffee',
    [...]
    {pattern: '../node_modules/q/q.js', included: false}
],
```